# Find the area of a triangle inscribed in the ellipse

Tags: contest-math, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

(Unicamp Mathematics Olympiad) Let $\zeta$ denote the Carteasian region given by $\zeta = \{(x,y): \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1\}$. Let $A = (0,3), B = (x,y), C = (z,w)$ be points such that $A,B,C \in \zeta%$ and $\Delta ABC$ is equilateral. What is the area of $\Delta ABC$?

My approach: Since $B, C$ are homogeneous, I tried to do enough algebra so everything "cuts out". I used Gauss' formula for the area of a triangle given tree points, the fact that ${AB}^2 = {BC}^2 = {AC}^2$ and used the explicit equation of $\zeta$, but it ended up being too much algebra and I couldn't find an explicit result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points of the ellipse are parameterised by $(2 \cos \theta, 3 \sin \theta)$ & by symmetry it is clear that the points $B$ and $C$ will have coordinates  $(2 \cos \theta, 3 \sin \theta)$ & $(-2 \cos \theta, 3 \sin \theta)$. So the requirement of equilateralness gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
(4 \cos \theta)^2=  (4 \cos \theta)^2+ (3 (1-\sin \theta))^2 \\
4 \cos^2 \theta=  3 (1-\sin \theta))^2  \\
4 (1+\sin \theta) =  3 (1-\sin \theta) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
The factor $(1-\sin \theta)$ can be discarded as it corresponds to the the points being concurrent. So we have $\sin \theta =- \frac{1}{7}$ and $\cos \theta =- \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{7}$. The length of the sides of the triangle are  $\frac{16\sqrt{3}}{7}$ and the area of the triangle is $\color{blue}{\frac{192\sqrt{3}}{49}}$.

Comment: Can you explain the "symmetry" part?

Comment: @LucasHenrique We could have assumed the parmaeterisation of $B$ and $C$ to be $(2 \cos \theta, 3 \sin \theta)$ and $(2 \cos \phi, 3 \sin \phi)$ respectively. The condition that $\mid AB \mid  = \mid AC \mid $ would have than lead us to conclude that $\phi = \pi-\theta$. It should also be clear from the diagram in Jack's answer that this is the case.

Answer (score 7):

$A=(0,3)$ is a vertex of the given ellipse. If $ABC$ is equilateral, by symmetry we have that $B$ and $C$ share the same $y$-coordinate, hence they are points of the form

$$ B=\left(-2\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{9}},y\right),\qquad C=\left(2\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{9}},y\right) $$
with $y\in(-3,3)$.  In order that $ABC$ really is equilateral, we must have

$$ 3-y = \sqrt{3}\cdot 2\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{9}} $$
hence $y=-\frac{3}{7}$ and $BC=\frac{16}{7}\sqrt{3}$. It follows that $[ABC]=\color{red}{\frac{192}{49}\sqrt{3}}$.

[image]

Comment: It's not that easy to see why B and C are symmetric. :p

Comment: @LucasHenrique: well, then we may say to have found a solution by considering the symmetric case only. To check it is the only solution, one has to prove that $\widehat{BAC}=60^\circ, BA=AC$ and $B,C\in\mathcal{E}$ give that $BC$ is perpendicular to the ellipse major axis. Otherwise, we would have $BA>AC$ or $CA>AB$. By exploiting the ellipse equation or the convexity of the ellipse.

Comment: As an alternative, one may consider $\mathcal{E}'$ as $\mathcal{E}$ rotated around $A$ by an angle equal to $60^\circ$. It is pretty clear that $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{E}'$ intersect only at $A$ and at another point, hence there is a unique solution. The symmetric solution is a solution, so that's it.

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is a vertex of the ellipse. If we have $B(-x,y)$ and $C(x,y)$ with $\triangle{ABC}$ equilateral, its area is simply $\sqrt3x^2$. There are several ways to find $x$ such that $B$ and $C$ lie on the ellipse and the triangle is equilateral. One way is to find the intersection of the line $AB$ with the ellipse. The equation of this line is $y=\sqrt3x-3$. Substituting this into the equation of the ellipse and simplifying yields $x(7x+8\sqrt3)=0$, so $x=-\frac{8\sqrt3}7$ and the area of the triangle is ${192\sqrt3\over49}$.

Comment: Why do we have this relation between B and C?

Comment: $A(0,3)$ is a vertex of the ellipse, so the $y$-axis must be the angle bisector of the triangle as well, making it symmetric about the $y$-axis, too. The side $BC$ is therefore parallel to the $x$-axis.